Nuxt3 prerendering without running instance?
Standard build (npm run build) doesn't start a running server, but prerender needs it, why?
Running npm run build --prerender / npm run generate also start a nuxt instance, is there a way to avoid it?
From the docs for crawl-based-pre-rendering :

This will build your site, stand up a nuxt instance, and, by
default, prerender the root page / along with any of your site's pages
it links to, any of your site's pages they link to, and so on.

I mean, without prerendering I can build my app with both frontend and server side code and no running nuxt instance, so why prerender does need to have one?
How can I set up a ci/cd pipeline if npm run build --prerender doesn't exit after finishing the build?

npm run build builds for ssr and npm run generate creates static routes. Neither of these commands start a running server. Typically people use a host like netlify or vercel and you can specify what build command to use there. In the case of nuxt, npm run build causes nitro to build a server for netilify or vercel automatically and you don‘t have to worry about running a server. Nitro actually creates a serverless function that handles all requests with nuxt when you specify netlify as the nitro preset

@dbzx10299 - crawl-based-pre-rendering: "This will build your site, stand up a nuxt instance, and, by default, prerender the root page / along with any of your site's pages it links to, any of your site's pages they link to, and so on.". The docs states differently, am I missing something? I know somewhere in the application a websocket is created, but I'm sure I disabled it during prerendere checking process.prerender.

Nitro builds the server and detects the environment, then typically with ssr there will be a serverless edge function that acts as the server. The nuxt instance is basically a class that ties everything together so that plugins work, lifecycle events and so on. Whether you use ssr or ssg, there is always a nuxt instance. With npm run build you still have a nuxt instance. Check the output and dist dirs at the root

OK, what I'm asking is: how can I set up a CI/CD pipeline if build process doesn't ends when pre-rendering?

Ok, found the problem.
For my specific use case, my nuxt config define a nitro storage pointing to a redis host:
export default defineNuxtConfig({
    // ...
    nitro: {
        storage: {
            redisMaster = {
                driver  : 'redis',
                port    : 6379,
                host    : process.env.REDIS_HOST
                username: process.env.REDIS_USERNAME,
                password: process.env.REDIS_PASSWORD,
                db      : process.env.REDIS_DB,
                tls     : 0
            }
        }
    }
});

Somehow having redisMaster being defined at prerender time cause the build process to not ending.
To solve this I conditionally define and add it to the config checking on process.prerender.
